# Personalization in SItecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, personalization

I want to display some different sublayout if user has visit some page more than 2 times so I want to use this rules "where the visit no. compares to number" but I do not have idea how I can use it? I tried to add this rule and replace "number" to 2 but it is not working.

Comment: What revision of Sitecore 8 are you using? What do you mean by "I have no idea how I can use it" .Have you got the rule set up on a sub layout and published it?

Comment: There's a good article here on setting up personalization - http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2014/06/Sitecore-DMS-personalization-howto.aspx

Comment: `Where the visit no. compares to ...` rule means that it's user n-th visit on the site, not that user opened one of the pages multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

As Marek said this is not possible with the condition you are using. However you could adjust the Rule condition to achieve this by looking at the VisitPageIndex for the page.

```cs
public class ContactVisitPageIndexCondition<T> : OperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    public int No
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ID PageGUID 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ContactVisitPageIndexCondition()
    {
    }

    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ruleContext, "ruleContext");
        Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
        Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Session, "Tracker.Current.Session is not initialized");
        Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction, "Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction is not initialized");
        int contactVisitPageIndex  =  Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Item.Id == PageGUID).VisitPageIndex;
        switch (base.GetOperator())
        {
            case ConditionOperator.Equal:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex == this.No;
            }
            case ConditionOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex >= this.No;
            }
            case ConditionOperator.GreaterThan:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex > this.No;
            }
            case ConditionOperator.LessThanOrEqual:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex <= this.No;
            }
            case ConditionOperator.LessThan:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex < this.No;
            }
            case ConditionOperator.NotEqual:
            {
                return contactVisitPageIndex != this.No;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `VisitPageIndex` is a pain and only returns the index of the page was viewed in the Contact's Visit but this is a good answer - just replace `Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Item.Id == PageGUID).VisitPageIndex;` with `Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.Count(p => p.Item.Id.Equals(yourPageId))`

Answer (score 2):

As Marek Musielak said, `Where the visit no. compares to ..` related to visit to the site and not an individual page.

I had a look in the Sitecore API, its `Tracker` namespace and the closest property I can find to individual page view count is `VisitPageIndex` but decompiling the code and checking in `MongoDB` shows that is just **the index of the page was viewed for that visit** to the site so this won't work for you.

Looking in `MongoDB` there are no properties to store page views but it does store the `Pages` viewed for `Interactions` so you could write a custom rule counting the number of times that page is in the Pages array

e.g.

```cs
int pageViewed = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages.Count(p => p.Item.Id.Equals(yourPageId))
```

An alternative if you don't want to write custom is to change your approach a bit inline with how Sitecore personalisation scan work out of the box.

You'll want to use or create `profile keys` in the `Marketing Centre` e.g. 'Brand Aware'. Assign your new `profile key` to the page in question and assign it a score e.g. 10. This means that each time a user visits this page they will be given a 10 points in 'Brand Aware'.

Now for the personalisation bit. Create a new personalisation rule on the existing `sublayout` using 'where the value of the specific profile key compares to specific value' set it to hide if the score is `greater than or equal to` 20. Create another to display your new `sublayout` if the value is `greater than or equal to` 20.

I've wrote a blog about this if [you need more info](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/05/01/quick-start-guide-sitecore-personalisation-dynamic-content/)